# Can I lock my workspace?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6

Struggling with Illustrator, I keep dragging my panels out and it's super irritating. How do I lock them in place?

Answer (score 2):

Actually you could reset the work space each time your illustrator is started.

Make a startup script with extendscript that calls something like:

```
app.sendScriptMessage("Adobe Custom Workspace" , 
        "Switch Workspace", '<workspace="Essentials" >');
```

Then it will reset the work space each time you start

Comment: I'm not sure that would help, I'm doing it while working ha ha. But thank you for sharing that :D.

Answer (score 1):

You can't lock the workspace but if you keep modifying it I would suggest backing up the file:

Windows: `-C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CS6\Presets\en_US\Workspaces`

Mac : `-Mac HD/applications/adobe illustrator cs6/presets/en_us/workspaces`

Comment: It's just the toolbox. I'm not even sure how I am doing it, I must be missing when I try to resize or not holding down long enough to display the fly out menus.